# Installing bibtexparser via PIP results in incomplete module

Tags: python, attributeerror

I've been trying to parse some BibTeX records with the bibtexparser module, and I can't get it to work even using the same sample code found in the [bibtexparser documentation](http://bibtexparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html).

The code is:

```
import bibtexparser

bibtex = """@ARTICLE{Cesar2013,
author = {Jean César},
title = {An amazing title},
year = {2013},
month = jan,
volume = {12},
pages = {12--23},
journal = {Nice Journal},
abstract = {This is an abstract. This line should be long enough to test
multilines...},
comments = {A comment},
keywords = {keyword1, keyword2}
}
"""

with open('bibtex.bib', 'w') as bibfile:
    bibfile.write(bibtex)

with open('bibtex.bib') as bibtex_file:
    bibtex_str = bibtex_file.read()

bib_database = bibtexparser.loads(bibtex_str)
print(bib_database.entries)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-to-script...", line 12, in <module>
    bib_database = bibtexparser.loads(bibtex_str)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Furthemore, when I try to list the attributes of bibtexparser, "load" and "loads" aren't there:

```
dir(bibtexparser)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'bparser', 'bwriter', 'customization', 'info', 'latexenc']
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where did you get the module from, as it look incomplete. You can grab the code from https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser.

Comment: I installed it from pip: pip install bibtexparser

Comment: Looks like the pip version is broken. Download the zip from the github link (on the right, there is a button marked `Download ZIP`). Extract the zip, then cd into it and run `python setup.py install` to reinstall it with all the files. If your using unix|linux, you may need `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: You could add an issue on [github](https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser/issues), and link it to this question as well

Comment: Alright, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

The pip version is (and was before the new release) not broken. The poster referred to the wrong version of the documentation according the the installed version.